# Does Node.js cancel setInterval automatically?

Tags: node.js, setinterval

I use setInterval and later node-schedule to create a scheduled call every hour or so, but it looks like the call typically gets canceled after a few days.

```
const { scheduleJob } = require('node-schedule');

for (let i = 0; i < 24; ++i)
  scheduleJob(`0 ${i} * * *`, tensorFlowAPIs);
```

This is the node-schedule version.

```
setInterval(tensorFlowAPIs, 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

And this is the setInterval version.

tensorFlowAPIs is essentially just an async request.

Comment: May this be related? https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22149

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt looks like it is possible. I just went from Node.js 8 to Node.js 11...

Comment: The mentioned issue seems to be fixed in v10.9.0 as per https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22149#issuecomment-418545597

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt then idk, perhaps something else then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Node.js cancel setInterval automatically?

No.  `setInterval()` does not automatically get cancelled after some long duration of time.

If your program is stopped and then restarted, you would have to manually restart the `setInterval()` to keep it going.

Often issues with long running programs are due to a resource leak of some kind (file handles, memory leak or some other system resource) that causes the process to not be able to do its job after a long while.  Obviously the best way to avoid this is to have a perfect program that never leaks any important resource, but one way that programmers handle slow, hard-to-detect leaks over time (particularly if they may be in library code that the developer isn't familiar with or occur only in certain hard to simulate error conditions) is to restart their process every so often (once a day, perhaps).  That clears out the process of any leak objects and starts afresh.

Comment: I am looking all exceptions now to see if there is any leaks. I would think otherwise because all other features function normally and the process has a very small memory footprint (50 some MB)...

Comment: @AeroWang - Did you monitor your process and see a memory leak?  You can use various OS tools to see about other types of system resources.

Comment: Nothing found so far but it has only been 1 day, so, this is gonna take a while.

Comment: @AeroWang -  If you're a pretty low memory usage app, then my guess would be some sort of resource that your app uses (db connection handle, file handle, etc...).  FYI (don't know if it's relevant or not) there is [plenty of discussion](https://www.google.com/search?q=tensorflow+memory+leak&rlz=1C1KDEC_enUS826US826&oq=tensorflow&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4515j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) about leaks in tensorFlow.

Comment: Yeah but my tensorFlow doesn't even run on the same machine.

Comment: And it is healthy. I can manually trigger the training processes.

Comment: Well, something is running in node.js that talks to your tensorFlow machine.  That function `tensorFlowAPIs` is in node.js.

Comment: `tensorFlowAPIs` is essentially just an async request. It does two thing, schedule trainings and find and remove useless photos (both via http request).

Comment: Based on the log it looks like sometimes the network is down on this machine thus the calls don't go through.